# Error using C# to count the number of mysql database rows with specific string varibles in them and display them as int

Tags: c#, mysql

The code I am writing is to check how many employees are going to lunch at the same time. The information is in a MySQL table named: "edata" in the column named: "Lunchtime", and are stored as a string such as "4:00pm-5:00pm".

```
Name   |   Lunchtime
------------------------
Paul       4:00pm-5:00pm
Mike       4:00pm-5:00pm
Aaron      1:00pm-2:00pm
```

The ultimate goal is to count the number of shifts that are chosen by the "lunchTimes.Text" variable and display how many employees selected the shift as an int named: "count".

i.e. Program user selects the "4:00pm-5:00pm" option, and the program returns "2" since 2 employees have selected that time slot.

```
private void select_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        shiftLunch = lunchTimes.Text;

        string constring = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=password";
        string Query = "select count(Lunchtime) from database.edata where Lunchtime= '"+shiftLunch+"';";

        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

        conDataBase.Open();
        Int32 count = (Int32)cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar();


        Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Currently I am getting this error:

**"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in First_cSharp_App.exe
Additional information: Specified cast is not valid."**

At this line:

```
Int32 count = (Int32)cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar();
```

I'm new to this so I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: Are you sure your getting results back. ExecuteScalar I believe will return null if no rows are found.

Comment: That query concatenation looks like a sql injection opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns `object` which couldn't explicitly converted to `Int32` at Runtime.

The proper way will be doing the following:

```
int count = (int)(cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: No problem.. Feel free to up-vote and accept the answer.

Comment: I would like something like this better: int.Parse(cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); any reason to choose Convert?

Comment: `int count = (int)(cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar());` this should work there is not need to ConvertToInt32 if he's just returning a count

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, Thanks, but i'm not making a review on the OP code, in this case i chosen for just helping him to move by this hurdle.

Comment: I know you were, but why not just help him twice at once? I mean, it's better to get used to best practices the earliest...

Comment: ok this is weird, it literally stopped working. no additional changes just what was recommend. any thoughts?

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in First_cSharp_App.exe
Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.**